# Limit of parameters of hypergeometric function

Tags: limits, analysis, hypergeometric-function

I know there is a lot of questions and resources around for limits of hypergeometric functions, but I was not able to find something useful for my problem.

I have the following function:

$$
f_n(z) = {}_2F_1(1,-n;1+n;z)
$$

where $z$ is a real number in the interval $[-1,1]$, $n$ is an integer, and I want to compute the limit $f(z) = \lim _{n\to\infty}f_n(z)$. The limit seems to be well defined numerically, but I'm really struggling to find the asymptotic behaviour. I read [this paper](https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/S0377042702006271?token=CD040D3264CFCC1539DC803CDBF7D9841C20FA3C2089846A9FAC7F38C22FD578E52797F66BEF58F9940EEA30779DD6E2) which seems to discuss similar stuff to what I have (in particular, I think case B is exactly my limit) but I don't grasp how to to apply it to my case.

If the limit cannot be explicitly evaluated, I would be happy with some series expansion for high $n$, specially at the values $z=0$ and $z=\pm 1$. From [Gauss hypergeometric theorem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GausssHypergeometricTheorem.html) I can evaluate $f(1)=1/2$ -but that's all I got.

I also took a look to book tables and other answers, trying several integral representations andthen taking the limit, but without success. Any help is welcomed, thank you so much!

**UPDATE**: using [DLMF](https://dlmf.nist.gov/15.12) 15.2.7, as suggested, I get

$$f_n(-z) \sim \sqrt2 \left( \frac{1+z}{2\sqrt z} \right) ^n \left[ \sqrt n U\left (\frac{1}{2}, -\alpha \sqrt n \right) - \frac{\sqrt 2}{z-1} U\left(-\frac{1}{2}, -\alpha \sqrt n \right)\right]$$

being $U(k,x)$ the parabolic cylinder function and $\alpha$ given by 15.2.8 as $\alpha = \sqrt { \left(-2\log (1 - (z-1)^2/(z+1)^2) \right)}$. I tried to use the expansion [DLMF 12.9.1](https://dlmf.nist.gov/12.9) for the PC functions at first order,

$$U(k,x) \sim e^{-x^2/4} x^{-k-1/2}$$.

Then the expression above is simplified to

$$f_n(-z) \sim \sqrt2 \left( \frac{1+z}{2\sqrt z} \right) ^n e^{-\alpha^2 n /4} \left( \frac{\sqrt 2}{1-z} - \frac{1}{\alpha} \right) $$.

Now the only terms that depends on $n$ is the first one. However, this term goes just to $0$ or to $+\infty$ depending on the value of the fraction. Moreover, a clear divergence can be seen at $z\to 0$, in contradiction with my previous finding (and not consistent with my numerical experiments). I read that the approximation 15.12.7 just works for phase of $z$ less than $\pi$, making my approximation not useful for real $z$. Is this true? What can I do to circumvent this problem?

Comment: Have you tried Digital Library of Mathematical Functions, eq. 15.12.7 with a=1, b=0, and c=1?  Warning: you'll be dealing with a parabolic cylinder function, which fortunately gives you, for a=1, the well-known error function.

Comment: Is this approximation valid for real $z$? Because it says that we need to have $|\text{ph}z|<\pi$. But in the real interval $[-1,1]$ I believe this condition does not hold. I tried to do it anyway, using the series expansion of the parabolic cylinder functions, but the result is not compatible at all with the hypergeometric... (and I'm not able to get rid of $n$ at any point)

Comment: For $|z| < 1$, the limit can be evaluated as
$$f(z) = \sum_{k \geq 0} \lim_{n \to \infty}
 \frac {(n - k + 1)_k} {(n + 1)_k} (-z)^k =
\frac 1 {1 + z}.$$

Comment: That's it, thank you very much! It was simpler than I expected :)

Answer (score 2):

$$f_n(z) = {}_2F_1(1,-n;1+n;z)$$

Around $z=0$, we have
$$f_n(z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{n! \,(k-n-1)!}{(-n-1)! \,(k+n)!} z^k$$

Around $z=-1$, the first term of the expansion is
$$f_n(z)=\frac{1}{2} \left(1+\sqrt{\pi }\,\frac{ \Gamma (n+1)}{\Gamma
   \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}\right)-\frac{n}{2}  (z+1)+O\left((z+1)^2\right)$$